# Remove [] tags with php

Tags: php, regex

```
Pogodba o zaposlitvi (v nadaljevanju PZ) je ena izmed pogodb, za katero zakon zahteva posebno obličnost ter tudi natančno določa, kdo so lahko stranke PZ.[/B] [CUT] Zak..
```

How to remove all [] tags in php. So [/B] [CUT],...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use regex for this, using [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$string = 'foo [/B] [CUT] bar';
$pattern = '/\[\/?[A-Z]+\]/';
$processed = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```

`$processed` then contains

```
'foo   bar'
```

This assumes the tags will always contain capital letters and may have a single `/` in front of the tag name.

Comment: Just in case, if the tags can contain lowercase letters, simply change `[A-Z]` to `[a-zA-Z]` in `$pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

I thisnk you have to use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

to do that...

Answer (score -4):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
str_replace (array('[', ']'), '', your text here)
```

Comment: I think what the op wants to do is remove not only the brackets, but everything inside of them as well. IE, remove the markup.

Comment: George this not remove [] and its value

Comment: @onteria_ Yeah in that case str_replace wouldn't do the trick.

Comment: To be fair, the question didn't explicitly state the desired output.

Comment: @Tomalak Sure it did. "So [/B] [CUT],..."